# Specify archive-to directory in 7z

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, 7-zip, ubuntu-13.04

I'm running `7z a` from the command line and wish to specify the directory which the archive `.7z` file is to be in. I don't see, from [the `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/7z.1.html), a way to do this (and `-o` and `-w` don't do it). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path as part of the name of the compressed file you want to create.

Something like:

`7zip a /directoryName/archiveName.7z dirToCompress`